# How does the USS Enterprise 1701-D computer compare to the current supercomputers?

Tags: star-trek

What is the processing power of the USS Enterprise 1701-D main computer? How it does it compare to the processing power of super computers of 2012?

Comment: Of which day? This question might be too localized.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in canon (tv+movies) to answer this (but am not certain).  Or it'll be inconsistent.  Perhaps in a novel?

Comment: Voted to close as non-constructive.  Until a Trek episode gives us Linpack scores for the ship, any comparison will just be handwaving and nonsense.

Comment: This what this link says of the enterprise computers, how does that relate to supercomputers .. 
Operating system: LCARS (Library Computer Access and Retrieval System)
Memory access speed: 4600 kiloquads/second
Number of memory modules: 2048
Memory capacity of one module: 630000 kiloquads
Memory capacity of all modules: 1290,24 gigaquads
http://www.kasper-online.de/en/docs/startrek/ncc1701d.htm

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the TNG and other series writers used a fictional unit of computer power, the quad, just so that the computers wouldn't be seen as being ridiculously underpowered at some point in the future (Moore's Law being what it is, computers are already approximately 64,000 times more powerful than in 1987).

Add to that an unfortunate propensity for writers on Voyager to avoid reading the manual, and it is impossible to compare real computers to fiction.

Source: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Quad

Comment: "A [quad](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Quad) is a measurement of information in Federation computers." - I think it was a replacement for bytes, not hertz.  Storage, not CPU speed.  Although I suppose the question is for both.

Comment: True - but they it was used in some scripts seemed to indicate some use for processing power as well as storage ("14 kiloquad processors" - you don't normally associate storage as a processor rating value)

Comment: 32-bit processors and 64-bit processors  ;)

Comment: okay... i might just have to hand in my developer licence now... *facepalm*

Comment: Voyager’s primary computer actually works at a speed of 575 trillion calculations per nanosecond according to the episode "Concerning Flight". Given that Voyager started near the same star date as next generation ended, I think it's reasonable to assume that the TNG enterprise had processing power somewhere close to that-

https://www.quora.com/Are-todays-super-computers-at-122-3-petaflops-per-second-faster-than-the-Star-Trek-Voyager-computer-at-500-trillion-calculations-per-second